# What are the characters which mark the beginning of a Google Sheet Formula?

Tags: google-sheets, syntax, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I am trying to find out characters that marks the beginning of a formula in Google Sheets (or Excel) in order to filter out characters in order to prevent Command Injections (e.g. **=IMPORTDATA()**).

The only ones that I know are '=' (equal sign) and '+' (plus sign) characters.

I tried searching it on the official websites but to no luck.
Does anyone know other characters that might work besides those?

Comment: Why tag Excel? how is that relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Google Sheets Formulae can start with either a `=` or `+`. These are the only two.*

#### More Information:

There's no *official* documentation for this (and actually the [support page](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/46977?hl=en&ref_topic=1361471) only mentions the use of `=`), but you can test it yourself. Run through each ASCII character and use it to prefix a formula using `setFormula()`:

```js
function myFunction() {  
  for(var i = 32; i < 127; i++) {
    var c = String.fromCharCode(i);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0]
      .getRange(i - 31, 1)
      .setFormula(c + "SUM(2+3)");
  }
}
```

After running, you get a column full of `#ERROR!`, `#NAME?`, and `#N/A` errors, and four cells which have been evaluated.

The cells which get evaluated to formulae correspond to the ASCII symbols `=`, `+`, `-` and   (space).

From here we can then test directly the four characters by entering them manually:

- `+SUM(2+3)` evaluates to 5, so `+` is a valid prefix.
- `=SUM(2+3)` evaluates to 5, so `=` is also valid prefix.
- `-SUM(2+3)` stays as a string so `+` is not a valid prefix.
- `SUM(2+3)` does not get evaluated, and so can not be used either.

**Side note:** According to [Microsoft's documentation on Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overview-of-formulas-in-excel-ecfdc708-9162-49e8-b993-c311f47ca173):

> Note: Formulas in Excel always begin with the equal sign.

#### References:

- [Add formulas & functions - Computer - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/46977?hl=en&ref_topic=1361471)
- [Overview of formulas in Excel - Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overview-of-formulas-in-excel-ecfdc708-9162-49e8-b993-c311f47ca173)

Answer (score 1):

**`=`** / **`+`** ...well those are the only ones, although only the equal sign is used as a marker of formula function.

both signs can be escaped by **`'`** character

there is no official Google documentation on this topic - as always